# How to parsing message with same struct from udp packet?

Tags: c#, struct, binary, udp

My app listening udp port and i receiving some message with this struct.
Struct entry:

```
{
    long price;
    char type;
    char flag;
    int amount;
    long time;
}
```

and i receiving binary message, but how i can parsing?
I know about unsafe method, but to me, it is not appropriate.
I have this function:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]    
unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    public long price;
    public char type;
    public char flag;
    public int amount;
    public long time;

    public fixed byte OptionalBytes[50];
    public fixed int OptionalInts[10];

    public static MyStruct Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        fixed (byte* pData = &data[0])
        {
            return *(MyStruct*)pData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the word ordering isn't an issue, just stuff your message into memory somewhere, and then cast the pointer to be a `*your_struct` pointer, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `byte[]` for the UDP datagram in a `MemoryStream` object, then wrap that in a `BinaryReader`. This will allow you to read the individual fields as necessary. For example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public long price;
    public char type;
    public char flag;
    public int amount;
    public long time;

    public byte[] OptionalBytes; // 50 bytes
    public int[] OptionalInts;   // 10 ints (i.e. 40 bytes)

    public static MyStruct Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        MyStruct result = new MyStruct();

        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream))
        {
            result.price = reader.ReadInt64();
            result.type = reader.ReadChar();
            result.flag = reader.ReadChar();
            result.amount = reader.ReadInt32();
            result.time = reader.ReadInt64();

            OptionalBytes = reader.ReadBytes(50);

            if (OptionalBytes == 50)
            {
                try
                {
                    result.OptionalInts = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                        .Select(i => reader.ReadInt32()).ToArray();
                }
                catch (EndOfStreamException)
                {
                    // incomplete...ignore
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // incomplete...ignore
                result.OptionalBytes = null;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note: I made something up for the "Optional" fields; your question didn't specify how those were to be dealt with, so I had no way to know exactly what the right thing for those was. I presume that the above example gives you enough of an idea of the general technique that you can figure out for yourself exactly how to handle those fields.